# Powershell ConvertTo-Json, OutOfMemoryException error

Tags: json, powershell, out-of-memory

I have a script that checks if a user has a photo in 365, and if not, checks to see if we have a photo for the user on file. If we do have a photo it will upload using Set-UserPhoto (I do not have access to Set-MgUserPhotoContent in our environment).

Issue being, after uploading about 5-6 photos, I get a "ConvertTo-Json : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown" error. Looking for suggestions and code examples of how I would prevent this so I can generate a report a the end of the script.

```
foreach ($Object in $PictureStatus) {
    $Name = $Object.DisplayName
    $Picture= Get-MgUserPhoto -UserID $Object.UserPrincipalName -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing' -CurrentOperation $name -PercentComplete (($counter / $picturestatus.count) * 100)
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200

        if ($Picture -ne $Null){
              
                        #has a picture in O365.
                        $Properties = [ordered]@{'UserName'=$Name;'Picture Present'='True';'Picture on File'='NA';'Picture Uploaded'='False'}

                        $Output_365Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties


                     }Else {

                        $TempVari=Get-ChildItem -Filter "$Name*" -File -Path $PhotoDatabase | where Length -gt 14kb
                        #Write-Output $TempVari                      

                              if ($TempVari -eq $null){
            
                                    #no Picture in Database
                                    $Properties = [ordered]@{'UserName'=$Name;'Picture Present'='False';'Picture on File'='False';'Picture Uploaded'='False'}

                                    $Output_365Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties

                              } else{
            
                                    #Photo Upload to 365
                                    Set-UserPhoto -Identity $Object.SamAccountName -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PhotoDatabase"+"\$TempVari")) -Confirm:$False
                                    
                                    $Properties = [ordered]@{'UserName'=$Name;'Picture Present'='False';'Picture on File'='True';'Picture Uploaded'='True'}

                                    $Output_365Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
                                }
                                
}
```

I have experimented with using [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new() instead of ReadAllBytes, but havent been able to get the code to work with Set-UserPhoto. I am not an expert on Powershell (for now)..

Comment: [try avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is inefficiënt in performance and memory usage.

Comment: @iRon I have tried completely eliminating the use of the array and instead exporting the results immediately - I am still getting an OutofMemoryException. I have learned however it is iterating through around 118 users (out of ~400) before the out of memory occurs. I have also learned that the Out of memory may not be related to the upload of pictures, because the most recent run did not upload any pictures.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `Set-UserPhoto` cmdlet but if you state "*did not upload any pictures*" it could mean that they didn't arrive at the server and all buffered at the client. To confirm your suggestion, I would simply comment-out the `Set-UserPhoto` command. As an aside: [`$Null` should be at the lefthandside of the comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null#checking-for-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the Out of memory error was being caused by the Size of the photo being uploaded.. If the image was above roughly 3 MB it could kick out an error. If I added -erroraction "continue" to the command the script keeps running fine, uploading anything of an appropriate size.

If anyone has a suggestion on how to upload the photos larger I am all ears, however for now the script is mostly working (Script is logging the errors and generates a report). For now, worst case scenario is we manually resize the photos above 3 MB and upload them again.

Comment: If your using O365 your not going to be able to upload any huge files here - its only a thumbnail after all. I would add a check for the file size in your code, if its too big then use something like ImageMagick to create a thumnail sized version and upload that instead. https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/

Comment: It seems the image only needs to be 96x96 pixels (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/image-dimensions-and-sizes-in-office-365/bc39d79a-c95a-4359-9153-db57fffd329d) - thats the size its displayed at. Anything bigger than a few 10's of KBs for a JPEG is far too big / is a waste of bandwidth. Apparently the O365 max file size appears to be 4MB - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-your-profile-photo-to-microsoft-365-2eaf93fd-b3f1-43b9-9cdc-bdcd548435b7?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us (btw you should accept your own answer if you resolved your issues)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can fix your problem

```
$Output_365Report = @()

foreach ($Object in $PictureStatus) {
    $Name = $Object.DisplayName
    $Picture = Get-MgUserPhoto -UserID $Object.UserPrincipalName -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Processing' -CurrentOperation $Name -PercentComplete (($counter / $PictureStatus.Count) * 100)
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200

    if ($Picture -ne $Null) {
        # Has a picture in O365.
        $Properties = [ordered]@{
            'UserName' = $Name
            'Picture Present' = 'True'
            'Picture on File' = 'NA'
            'Picture Uploaded' = 'False'
        }
    } else {
        $TempVari = Get-ChildItem -Filter "$Name*" -File -Path $PhotoDatabase | Where-Object Length -gt 14kb

        if ($TempVari -eq $null) {
            # No Picture in Database
            $Properties = [ordered]@{
                'UserName' = $Name
                'Picture Present' = 'False'
                'Picture on File' = 'False'
                'Picture Uploaded' = 'False'
            }
        } else {
            # Photo Upload to 365
            foreach ($File in $TempVari) {
                Set-UserPhoto -Identity $Object.SamAccountName -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PhotoDatabase\$($File.Name)")) -Confirm:$False

                $Properties = [ordered]@{
                    'UserName' = $Name
                    'Picture Present' = 'False'
                    'Picture on File' = 'True'
                    'Picture Uploaded' = 'True'
                }
                break # Assuming you only want to upload one picture per user
            }
        }
    }

    $Output_365Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
}

$Output_365Report | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
```

Comment: Please write something about how this is different than the OP's original code. What is different about this code that might work?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - however this did not work. Script never makes it to "$Output_365Report | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99" error occurs before that point. foreach ($Object in $PictureStatus) { is looping through roughly 400 users. 

As I mentioned, typically it uploads 6 photos before the Json Error appears.

Comment: Error: 
ConvertTo-Json : Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
At C:\Users\user-admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_pqwxaynt.e1m\tmpEXO_pqwxaynt.e1m.psm1:1442 char:17
+         $Body = ConvertTo-Json $BodyObj -Depth 10 -Compress
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertTo-Json], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.OutOfMemoryException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToJsonCommand